# Deploying Flower to Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, celery, flower

I'm following the instructions on https://github.com/jorilallo/celery-flower-heroku to deploy Flower celery monitoring app to Heroku.

After configuring and deploying my app I see the following in heroku logs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/bin/flower", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('flower==0.7.0', 'console_scripts', 'flower')()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flower/__main__.py", line 11, in main
    flower.execute_from_commandline()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 306, in execute_from_commandline
    return self.handle_argv(self.prog_name, argv[1:])
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flower/command.py", line 99, in handle_argv
    return self.run_from_argv(prog_name, argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flower/command.py", line 75, in run_from_argv
    **app_settings)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flower/app.py", line 40, in __init__
    max_tasks_in_memory=max_tasks)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flower/events.py", line 60, in __init__
    state = shelve.open(self._db)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/shelve.py", line 239, in open
    return DbfilenameShelf(filename, flag, protocol, writeback)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/shelve.py", line 223, in __init__
    Shelf.__init__(self, anydbm.open(filename, flag), protocol, writeback)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/anydbm.py", line 85, in open
    return mod.open(file, flag, mode)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/dumbdbm.py", line 250, in open
    return _Database(file, mode)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/dumbdbm.py", line 71, in __init__
    f = _open(self._datfile, 'w')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'postgres://USERNAME:PASSWORD@ec2-HOST.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/DBNAME.dat'
```

Notice the `.dat` appendix there? No idea where it comes from, its not present int my `DATABASE_URL` env variable.

Furthermore, the error above is with flower 0.7. I also tried installing 0.6, with which I do get further (namely the DB is correctly recognized and connection established), but I then get the following warnings once flower starts:

```
2014-06-19T15:14:02.464424+00:00 app[web.1]: [E 140619 15:14:02 state:138] Failed to inspect workers: '[Errno 104] Connection reset by peer', trying again in 128 seconds
2014-06-19T15:14:02.464844+00:00 app[web.1]: [E 140619 15:14:02 events:103] Failed to capture events: '[Errno 104] Connection reset by peer', trying again in 128 seconds.
```

Loading flower in my browser does show a few tabs of stuff, but there is no data.

How do I resolve these issues?

Comment: How did you get this to work?

Comment: Sorry, I can't really recall. I remember we had flower working, but IIRC not with Postgres, something more ephemeral (i.e. data was not kept after dyno restarts). That is, IIRC. I really am not sure, it was 4 years ago.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flower doesn't support database persistence. It saves the state to file(s) using  [shelve](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html) module.